# Can an app send Inbox message to its users?

Tags: facebook, notifications, inbox

If so,

How can it be done?
Do you maybe know the Facebook policy about sending inbox messages?

Comment: this can not be done. *Thankfully*.  It would be too spammy and applications could abuse the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Your app can prompt the user for 'email' extended permissions and then you could email the user from your mail server.  But their isn't an API method to send Facebook messages as spammers would abuse that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but I do believe that you mean the users Facebook inbox, not your e-mail inbox - right?

**In that case you can use:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

I hope that this is what you mean.